# What is the difference between fine tuning and variants of few shot learning?

Tags: deep-learning, fine-tuning, pretrained-models, few-shot-learning, zero-shot-learning

I am trying to understand the concept of fine-tuning and few-shot learning.

I understand the need for fine-tuning. It is essentially tuning a pre-trained model to a specific downstream task.

However, recently I have seen a plethora of blog posts stating zero-shot learning, one-shot learning and few-shot learning.

How are they different from fine-tuning? It appears to me that few-shot learning is a specialization of fine-tuning. What am I missing here?

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: @nbro no. They don't discuss about few shot learning and their difference.

Comment: Ok, then edit your post to explain that you're just interested in few-shot learning and why that other post doesn't answer your question.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the standard meanings are as follows, but not everyone uses words in the same way, so you might see examples that differ.

**Fine tuning** refers to slightly changing the weights of a pre-trained model (i.e. using a low learning rate) to adapt to a specific task.

**Few shot learning** refers to using a very small dataset to adapt to a specific task.

Someone might do both at the same time (fine-tuning with a small dataset), just fine-tuning (with a big dataset), or just few shot learning (e.g. giving GPT a few examples to prompt a particular kind of answer).